# sfc scannow offbootdir=d:\ /offwindr=d:\windows server 2008 runtime

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, bsod

I've been getting bluescreen restarts during windows boot on a server 2008R2 machine. I've been running "sfc scannow offbootdir=d:\ /offwindr=d:\windows" for about 7 hours now. The windows partion is only 50GB. Is this a normal runtime on a Dell R610?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's an excessively long time.  I suspect sfc is finding a bunch of problems or one problem with a bunch of side effects making the run time really long.

Comment: I ended up Killing SFC after 14 hours. Doesn't appear to have fixed anything.